# Can't add single XML file to Tomcat's classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, classpath

I want to add a file to the classpath of all applications running on my Tomcat 7 server.

When adding

```
${catalina.base}/conf/myfile.xml
```

to `common.loader` in `catalina.properties` it's not working.

But adding just

```
${catalina.base}/conf
```

does the trick.

However, I just want to add a specific file, not the entire directory. The comments in `catalina.properties` state the following:

> […] Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type. […]
>
> […] Examples: "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository […]

Unfortunately I haven't found out with which prefix I should mark my file. Do you know more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add something to the classpath, it it always either an whole directory; or a whole JAR file (which you may consider as an packed directory). You may never have a single file entry in your classpath.

Proposed solution: Either live with the conf/ directory; or pack your `myfile.xml` in a JAR file (even if it only contains a single file).